# PHP rtrim all trailing special characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm making a function that that detect and remove all trailing special characters from string. It can convert strings like :

- "**hello-world**"
- "**hello-world/**"
- "**hello-world--**"
- "**hello-world/%--+...**"

into "hello-world".

anyone knows the trick without writing a lot of codes?

Comment: sorry, it was wrong, it is "hello".

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun

```
[^a-z\s]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tE1kG7/1)

**Explanation:**
`[^x]`: One character that is not x [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bB0vG6/1)
`\s`: "whitespace character": space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab [sample](https://regex101.com/r/pD4dR7/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)

PHP:

```
$re = "/[^a-z\\s]+/i";
$str = "Hello world\nhello world/\nhello world--\nhellow world/%--+...";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
```

or escape apostraphe from string

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\']/', '', $string);  // escape apostraphe
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex like this, depending on your definition of "special characters":

```
function clean_string($input) {
    return preg_replace('/\W+$/', '', $input);
}
```

It replaces any characters that are not a word character (`\W`) at the end of the string `$` with nothing. `\W` will match `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so anything that is not a letter, digit, or underscore will get replaced. To specify which characters are special chars, use a regex like this, where you put all your special chars within the `[]` brackets:

```
function clean_string($input) {
    return preg_replace('/[\/%.+-]+$/', '', $input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is what you are looking for. :

`([^\n\w\d \"]*)$`

It removes anything that is not from the alphabet, a number, a space and a new line.
Just call it like this :

`preg_replace('/([^\n\w\s]*)$/', '', $string);`

Comment: You don't need the `\d` the `\w` includes that. It also allows underscores.

Comment: Oh yes.. Thank you for that.